# Segmentation fault on one Linux machine but not another with C++ code

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, portability

I have been having a peculiar problem. I have developed a C++ program on a Linux cluster at work. I have tried to use it home on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine, but the program, which is composed of 6 files: main.hpp,main.cpp (dependent on) sarsa.hpp,sarsa.cpp (class Sarsa) (dependent on) wec.hpp,wec.cpp, does compile, but when I run it it either returns `segmenation fault` or does not enter one fundamental function of the class `Sarsa`.

The main code calls the constructor and setter functions without problems:

```
  Sarsa run;
  run.setVectorSize(memory,3,tilings,1000);
```

etc.

However, it cannot run the public function `episode` , since `learningRate`, which should contain a large integer, returns 0 for all episodes (iterations).

```
learningRate[episode]=run.episode(numSteps,graph);}
```

I tried to debug the code with gdb, which has returned:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000408f4a in main () at main.cpp:152
152     learningRate[episode]=run.episode(numSteps,graph);}
```

I also tried `valgrind`, which returned:

```
==10321==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==10321==    at 0x408CAD: main (main.cpp:112)
```

But no memory leakage issues.

I was wondering if there was a setting to try to debug the external file `sarsa.cpp`, since I think that class is likely to be the culpript

In the file, I use C++v11 language (I would be expecting errors at compile-time,though), so I even compiled with `g++ -std=c++0x`, but there were no improvements.

Unluckily, because of the size of the code, I cannot post it here. I would really appreciate any help with this problem. Am I missing anything obvious? Could you help me at least with the debugging?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Correction:
`main.cpp:`

Definition of the global array:
`#define numEpisodes 10

int learningRate[numEpisodes];`

Towards the end of the `main` function:

`for (int episode; episode<numEpisodes; episode++) {
    if (episode==(numEpisodes-1)) {  // Save the simulation data only at the
      graph=true;}                   // last episode
    learningRate[episode]=run.episode(numSteps,graph);}`

Comment: 1. Since the segfault happens in code derived from `main.cpp`, that would seem to be a better place to start.  The most likely causes of a segfault at main.cpp:152 would be `learningRate` being an uninitialized pointer (note Valgrind's warning) or `epsiode` not being a valid index into it the static or dynamic array referenced by `learningRate`.

Comment: 2. Having the source split among multiple files does not present any special or unusual challenge for `gdb` or most other debuggers.  Debugging a program built from multiple sources Just Works.  If the debugger can find `main.cpp` (which it can) and you have not changed the relative locations of the other sources, then it will find the others, too.

Comment: At the end of my question I have added the parts of `main.cpp` where `learningRate` can be found. I cannot see why `learningRate` should be an uninitialized pointer

Comment: Rhetorical question: given `for (int episode; episode<numEpisodes; episode++)`, what is the value of `episode` at the beginning of the first iteration of the loop body?

Comment: Thank you very much! I cannot believe I wasted some hours on this, trying to look for errors in the class, when I simply did not initialize episode.

Comment: If you post an answer I will vote it as solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the code you just added to the question reveals, the problem arises because you did not initialize the `episode` variable.  The behavior of any code that uses its value before you assign one is undefined, so it is entirely reasonable that the program behaves differently in one environment than in another.

Answer (score 2):

A segmentation fault indicates an invalid memory access.  Usually this means that somewhere, you're reading or writing past the end of an array, or through an invalid pointer, or through an object that has already been freed.  You don't necessarily get the segmentation fault at the point where the bug occurs; for instance, you could write past the end of an array onto heap metadata, which causes a crash later on when you try to allocate or release an unrelated object.  So it's perfectly reasonable for a program to appear to work on one system but crash on another.

In this case, I'd start by looking at `learningRate[episode]`.  What is the value of `episode`?  Is it within the bounds of `learningRate`?

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there was a setting to try to debug the external file `sarsa.cpp`, since I think that class is likely to be the culpript

[It's possible to set breakpoints in functions other than `main.cpp`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html#Set-Breaks).

> break *location*
>
> Set a breakpoint at the given *location*, which can specify a function name, a line number, or an address of an instruction.

At least, I think that's your question.  [You'll also need to know how to step into functions](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#Continuing-and-Stepping).

More importantly, you need to learn what your tools are trying to tell you.  A segfault is the operating system's reaction to an attempt to dereference memory that doesn't belong to you.  One common reason for that is trying to dereference `NULL`.  Another would be trying to dereference a pointer that was never initialized.  The Valgrind error message suggests that you may have an unitialized pointer.

Without the code, I can't tell you why the pointer isn't initialized when you run the program on your home system, but is (apparently) initialized when you run it at work.  I suspect that you don't have the necessary data on your home system, but you'll need to investigate and figure that out.  The fundamental question to keep asking yourself is "what is different between my home computer an dmy work computer?"